# Ubuntu changing Windows partition files triggers Windows chkdsk

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04/Windows 7 laptop and have noticed that every time I edit a file on my Windows partition while in Ubuntu, the next time I boot into Windows it runs chkdsk to (I assume) undo whatever I just changed.

Is this something you can override, or is there a way to edit these files without having problems?

Comment: did you hibernate Windows ??

Comment: It seems strange that you'd assume it undoes changes you make to files without having seen that actually happen.

Comment: I have the same suspicion as Mark Yisri: Fast startup is a hibernating feature in Windows. It should be turned off in order to avoid this kind of problems in dual boot systems. In general, please avoid editing or writing in the Windows partition. It is better to have a separate **data** partition with the NTFS file system for personal files that you want to access from both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it make changes to my files, but I'm not sure if it was a rollback or not.  This last time, I did not hibernate Windows, although I did have that problem before as well.  I do have a separate data partition which does not have this problem so @sudodus suggestion is confirmed.